# Powershell foreach variable passing to az cli query missing

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I am trying to retrieve the resource id from within a foreach but nothing is being returned, when looking at the debug output, the value of $item is empty.

sample code:

```
$vnetPNames=@("Name1","Name2","Name3")

foreach ($item in $vnetPNames) {

$getId = az network vnet list --query "`"[?name =='$item'].id`"" -o tsv

az network vnet peering create ...
}
```

any pointers to the simple item i am missing here?

Comment: Is this the actual code you're running? There's a `"` missing from `"[?name =='$item'].id -o tsv`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you for spotting my typo, I've updated and addressed this.

Comment: Is the `$` missing from `vnetPNames` in the first line also a typo? :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you for spotting another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and i got expected results :

I have seen that

[image]
your code has extra " (quotations) .

The code that worked for me is :

```
$vnetPNames=@("Rith123","bojja123")
foreach ($item in $vnetPNames) {
$getId = az network vnet list --query "[?name =='$item'].id" -o tsv 
}
```

[image]

Here Rith123 and bojja123 are Vnet Names.

Please try to edit your code accordingly and you will get item.